# Are Launchpad questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since Launchpad is an integral part of Ubuntu, would questions relating to the use of Launchpad be on-topic?

Obviously questions about *a specific project* on Launchpad would be off-topic. (Unless there's another good reason for the question.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think they should be considered ontopic.

For more advanced users who might need to follow the progress of a bug or report a bug it can be useful.

And for developers (especially SE people who are unfamiliar with Ubuntu) it's a great opportunity to showcase the things Launchpad can offer them as application developers (daily builds, bug tracking, PPAs, etc.) - which in turn get consumed by Ubuntu users.

Comment: Thanks for giving a detailed answer - I shall now ask my question on the site!

Answer (score 4):

I think that aksubuntu.com can provide an user friendly service for learning how Launchpad helps Ubuntu.
In the same time, I am not sure if the LP developers are using askubuntu.com.

For better results I suggest using the [Launchpad users mailinglist list](https://launchpad.net/~launchpad-users) (I know is not that user friendly ... but rather developer friendly) or ask a question in the [„Answers” section for Launchpad itself](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/132734).